# Is there a callback in Dart polymer element called before repaint

Tags: dart, repaint, dart-polymer

I have model class and Polymer view element displaying model data. Model doesn't know about the Polymer element, there is some event interface:

```dart
onModelChanged;
int _x;
get x=>_x;
set x(val){
  _x=val;
  onModelChanged();
}
```

In Polymer element I want to check for changes before the next repaint, because the model is changed many times per frame (some physics). Is there any way how I can get `onBeforeRepaint`?
(I know, that polymer does not match well in this case. This is experimental use case.)

Comment: I really don't know your problem and what you want to accomplish, but maybe you want to have a look at `window.requestAnimationFrame` this is the function where you would do some checking / calculation.

Comment: Thaks I know that function well. I am trying to clear my code from many raf loops or some subscriber. I solved my problem for now with one global raf loop and subscriber.